# Button Copy to Clipboard window location href

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, window

I want to copy the current `window.location.href` onClick in the button, even if i set the right state i can not actually copy it, what is my problem?

Here the code

```
const [copyHref, setCopyHref] = useState(JSON.stringify(window.location.href));

  const copyToClipboard = () => {
    setCopyHref(copyHref)
    document.execCommand(copyHref);
    alert("Copied the text: " + copyHref);
  };

<Button onClick={copyToClipboard}/>
```

When i click i get the alert with the right `url`, but it does not actually copy it. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.href`, to the best of my knowledge, is a string. So I am not quite sure what your goal is with `JSON.stringify(window.location.href)`.

I am also puzzled as to your use of the state to accomplish this basic function.

As for copying the URL into clipboard, I would accomplish it like so:

```
export default function App() {
  const copyToClipboard = () => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(window.location.href).then(function() {
      alert("copied successfully!")
    }, function(err) {
      alert('Failed to copy');
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={copyToClipboard}> copy </button>    
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function execCommand does not work like this. You need to specify which command to execute and it not specifically for copying.
Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard for more details.
Also you can use the native js function copy() for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
const copyToClipboard = () => {
 navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyHref);
 alert("Copied the text: " + copyHref);
};
```